# CTE For computing bill of material quantity

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Given this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dff61/2/0), I am trying to figure out to pull the correct quantity for the item with the FileID 140129. The query returns 18, but the total should be 24 as the parent quantity for FileID 140111 is 2. I have tried various places to multiply the parent by the child but I'm having a mental block. Any suggestions?

[image: Excel view]

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [PartName] varchar(10), [ParentID] int, [FileID] int, [RefCount] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [PartName], [ParentID], [FileID], [RefCount])
VALUES
    (1, 'DemoParent', 0, 139209, 1),
    (2, '78200', 139209, 140072, 1),
    (3, '78180', 139209, 140087, 1),
    (4, '78160', 139209, 140117, 1),
    (5, '78140', 139209, 140145, 1),
    (6, '78148', 140066, 140129, 6),
    (7, '78203', 140068, 140066, 1),
    (8, '78202', 140072, 140068, 1),
    (9, '78148', 140081, 140129, 3),
    (10, '78183', 140083, 140081, 1),
    (11, '78182', 140087, 140083, 1),
    (12, '78148', 140111, 140129, 6),
    (13, '78163', 140113, 140111, 2),
    (14, '78162', 140117, 140113, 2),
    (15, '78148', 140139, 140129, 3),
    (16, '78143', 140145, 140139, 1)
;
;WITH BomQty (ParentFileID, FileID, RefCount)
AS
(
    SELECT t1.ParentID, t1.FileID, t1.RefCount
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.ParentID = 0
    UNION  ALL
 SELECT t1.ParentID, t1.FileID, t1.RefCount
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN BomQty AS bq
        ON t1.ParentID = bq.FileID

)
SELECT bq.FileID, SUM(bq.RefCount)
FROM BomQty bq 
WHere FileID = 140129
GROUP BY bq.FileID
```

Comment: @RubensFarias - Aye, it was a typo. 140111 is correct.

Comment: So you wanna to sum `RefCount` for the FileID and only the immediate parent, right? Or all the way to the top?

Comment: It should be a total count for every row, so to the top. 24 is the correct sum of `RefCount` in this case.

Comment: I'm coming up with 23. What am I missing? I'll post my solution below, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @Jon See my comment to Ruben's answer below. The count for each item is its `RefCount` multiplied its parents `RefCount`, and then totalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to multiply `Count` field by its immediate parentID value. We can start with first level, saving the current value and a reference to the parent one, and recurse it to the top, like this:

```
;WITH   Data    AS
(       SELECT  *
        FROM    (
            VALUES  (01, 'DemoParent', 0, 139209, 1),
                    (02, '78200', 139209, 140072, 1),
                    (03, '78180', 139209, 140087, 1),
                    (04, '78160', 139209, 140117, 1),
                    (05, '78140', 139209, 140145, 1),
                    (06, '78148', 140066, 140129, 6),
                    (07, '78203', 140068, 140066, 1),
                    (08, '78202', 140072, 140068, 1),
                    (09, '78148', 140081, 140129, 3),
                    (10, '78183', 140083, 140081, 1),
                    (11, '78182', 140087, 140083, 1),
                    (12, '78148', 140111, 140129, 6),
                    (13, '78163', 140113, 140111, 2),
                    (14, '78162', 140117, 140113, 2),
                    (15, '78148', 140139, 140129, 3),
                    (16, '78143', 140145, 140139, 1)
                ) Data([ID], [PartName], [ParentID], [FileID], [RefCount])
),      BomQty  AS
(       SELECT  [ID], [FileId] AS [Current], [RefCount] AS [Total], 1 As Level
        FROM    Data
        WHERE   ParentID = 0
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  Data.[ID], Data.[FileId],
                Data.[RefCount] * BomQty.[Total], BomQty.Level + 1
        FROM    BomQty  -- Magic happens here
        JOIN    Data
            ON  Data.[ParentID] = BomQty.[Current]
)
SELECT  [Current], SUM(Total) Quantity
FROM    BomQty
GROUP
    BY  [Current]
```

I'am reading your data like this:

[image: Example]

1. To *produce* 1 x 139209 you'll need:

   - 1 x 140072

     - 1 x 140068

       - 1 x 140066

         - 6 x `140129`
   - 1 x 140087

     - 1 x 140083

       - 1 x 140081

         - 3 x `140129`
   - 1 x 140117

     - **2 x 140113**

       - 2 x 140111

         - 6 x `140129`
   - 1 x 140145

     - 1 x 140139

       - 3 x `140129`

That means you'll need a total of 36 x `140129` parts, right?

Comment: The total should be 24. The `RefCount` is the quantity of each item in the top level. Since 140129 is in the parent 140111 with a qty of 6, and that item has a `RefCount` of 2, the total for that is 12. The total for 140129 is 24. I need to multiply the `RefCount` for the `FileID` by the parent `RefCount`.

Comment: That will work for this sample data set, but unfortunately, it's not correct for a complete bill of material as the level will vary.

Comment: @ehcanadian, inverted the tree, check it now

Comment: Looking at the data, yes, you're correct, and that's probably why my various attempts looked off. Thank you for catching that and your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FileID, SUM(RefCount) + 
(
   SELECT SUM(RefCount) As ParentSum
   FROM Table1 t
   WHERE FileID IN(SELECT ParentID FROM Table1 t2 WHERE FileID = 140129)
)
FROM Table1 t
WHERE FileID = 140129
GROUP BY FileID;
```